# Google Bigquery SQL UNNEST and STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(inputs.addresses) as stringAgg, 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`
JOIN UNNEST (inputs) AS inputs
GROUP BY Date(block_timestamp)
```

However, I get the following error:

> *No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG for argument
>   types: ARRAY. Supported signatures: STRING_AGG(STRING);
>   STRING_AGG(STRING, STRING); STRING_AGG(BYTES); STRING_AGG(BYTES,
>   BYTES) at [2:3] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.*

Unsure how to get around this and get the list of addresses that are present in output. Error makes sense given the type addresses is:
[outputs. addresses STRING  REPEATED    Addresses which own this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputs.addresses` is an ARRAY by itself, so you need UNNEST it too
For example as in below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE(block_timestamp) AS block_date,
  STRING_AGG(address) AS stringAgg
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`
JOIN UNNEST (inputs) AS input, UNNEST(input.addresses) address
GROUP BY DATE(block_timestamp)
LIMIT 10
```

Obviously, above assumes that you want to collect all addresses per day as it is in your original query